# how to get date filter settings

Tags: views, datetime

I want to exposed date filter option
but am getting just textbox instaed of datepicker
I have installed date module still am not getting following options:
[image]

installed modules are as shown bellow:
[image]

Please guide me how to set datepicker and add search option using that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Date picker](https://drupal.org/project/datepicker) Module for **popup date** on exposed filter.

It includes the date popup. You can use this module to easily add an exposed filter with the date popup.

[image]

Comment: added still not getting those options? where I will get those options?

Comment: I have updated my answer :)

Comment: don't forget to enable the sub-module "Date Picker Views"